# OrientDB - Why does ETL need some time before beginning to load

Tags: mysql, etl, orientdb, graph-visualization

As you can see from the console output:

```
BEGIN ETL PROCESSOR
+ extracted 0 records (0 records/sec) - 0 records -> loaded 0 vertices (0 vertic
es/sec) Total time: 1055ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
+ extracted 0 records (0 records/sec) - 0 records -> loaded 0 vertices (0 vertic
es/sec) Total time: 2055ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
+ extracted 0 records (0 records/sec) - 0 records -> loaded 0 vertices (0 vertic
es/sec) Total time: 3389ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
+ extracted 0 records (0 records/sec) - 0 records -> loaded 0 vertices (0 vertic
es/sec) Total time: 4389ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
+ extracted 0 records (0 records/sec) - 0 records -> loaded 0 vertices (0 vertic
es/sec) Total time: 5389ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
+ extracted 0 records (0 records/sec) - 0 records -> loaded 0 vertices (0 vertic
es/sec) Total time: 6389ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
+ extracted 0 records (0 records/sec) - 0 records -> loaded 0 vertices (0 vertic
es/sec) Total time: 7488ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
+ extracted 0 records (0 records/sec) - 0 records -> loaded 0 vertices (0 vertic
es/sec) Total time: 8488ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
+ extracted 0 records (0 records/sec) - 0 records -> loaded 0 vertices (0 vertic
es/sec) Total time: 9658ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
+ extracted 236 records (234 records/sec) - 236 records -> loaded 235 vertices (
233 vertices/sec) Total time: 10663ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
```

You can my ETL config here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/JbMrhqSGXGM

So how it comes that in the first 10 seconds it does seem that he is doing nothing.

FYI: in the MySQL table are ~250.00 entries, just colums was taken from there

Comment: According to the link you wrote you have resolved.

Comment: Hey Luca, no not really. Because the remote:... (I think just under Windows) has a bug. So I can't test it as remote. But if you say it could be plocal as reason, well it's jsut a cosmetic aspect. Nothing bad, was just interested to know why he just started loading from the 10. second. And yes I was able to fix the other issue already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has something to do with the way you access the database. There can be plocal and remote and some more. You should test them out which one works best on a local massive import.